# Dismiss rows from DataFrame by condition in different one

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have two sets of csv, both with different time frequencies throughout- i.e Measurment every 5 minutes, then every hour etc.

What I want to do is for the second csv (`column 2`) if there is a value greater than `190` anywhere in that `hour`, then get rid of CSV one's respective hour

Is there a magical way using Pandas to do that? I was thinking of setting the condition to `true` and `false` as an index then timesing the first CSV data by that. but I thought for this, they would need to be the exact same data intervals.

CSV1 has data of kind (Date,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H):

```
24-jan-08 23:50,  -8.6,  7.7, 0.0213,  .9820, 0.0213, 1.6316, 1.00,46.810
24-jan-08 23:55,  -6.7,  7.7, 0.0213,  .9824, 0.0213, 1.6321, 1.00,46.802
25-jan-08 00:00,  -1.7,  7.7, 0.0213,  .9828, 0.0213, 1.6328, 1.00,46.799
25-jan-08 00:05,   -32,  7.7, 0.0213,  .9835, 0.0213, 1.6334, 1.00,46.757
25-jan-08 00:10, -11.1,  7.7, 0.0213,  .9842, 0.0213, 1.6342, 1.00,46.742
```

etc but as mentioned goes from 5 minutely to hourly later but CSV file is too big to post on here

CSV2 has data the kind (Date,A,B):

```
2008-01-24 23:50,6.55,186.9
2008-01-24 23:51,6.84,188.6  
2008-01-24 23:52,7.14,188.1
2008-01-24 23:53,7.12,189.9
2008-01-24 23:54,7.45,188.6
2008-01-24 23:55,7.52,190.5
2008-01-24 23:56,7.29,189.5
2008-01-24 23:57,7.07,192.4
2008-01-24 23:58,7.33,193.7
2008-01-24 23:59,7.25,192.6
2008-01-25 00:02,6.52,191
2008-01-25 00:03,6.58,189
2008-01-25 00:04,6.43,190.5
2008-01-25 00:05,6.6,188.3
2008-01-25 00:06,6.52,188.7
2008-01-25 00:07,6.75,188.9
2008-01-25 00:08,6.62,188.9
2008-01-25 00:09,6.26,188.8
2008-01-25 00:10,6.6,193.2
```

The 190 is entirely arbitary need to pick a number appropiate to full dataset

Comment: So in first dataset by second sample will be removed all data, because in hour 23 and 00 are values higher as 190?

Comment: Yeah so if during each hour of the second sample one of the results is say over 190, it will remove that hours worth of data set in the first sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup double [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""24-jan-08 23:50,-8.6,7.7,0.0213,.9820,0.0213,1.6316,1.00,46.810
24-jan-08 23:55,-6.7,7.7,0.0213,.9824,0.0213,1.6321,1.00,46.802
25-jan-08 00:00,-1.7,7.7,0.0213,.9828,0.0213,1.6328,1.00,46.799
25-jan-08 00:05,-32,7.7,0.0213,.9835,0.0213,1.6334,1.00,46.757
25-jan-08 00:10,-11.1,7.7,0.0213,.9842,0.0213,1.6342,1.00,46.742"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0], names=['Date','A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H'])

temp=u"""
2008-01-24 23:50,6.55,186.9
2008-01-24 23:51,6.84,188.6
2008-01-24 23:52,7.14,188.1
2008-01-24 23:53,7.12,189.9
2008-01-24 23:54,7.45,188.6
2008-01-24 23:55,7.52,190.5
2008-01-24 23:56,7.29,189.5
2008-01-24 23:57,7.07,192.4
2008-01-24 23:58,7.33,193.7
2008-01-24 23:59,7.25,192.6
2008-01-25 00:02,6.52,191
2008-01-25 00:03,6.58,189
2008-01-25 00:04,6.43,190.5
2008-01-25 00:05,6.6,188.3
2008-01-25 00:06,6.52,188.7
2008-01-25 00:07,6.75,188.9
2008-01-25 00:08,6.62,188.9
2008-01-25 00:09,6.26,188.8
2008-01-25 00:10,6.6,193.2"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0],names=['Date','A','B'])
```

```
print (df1)
                 Date     A    B        C       D       E       F    G       H
0 2008-01-24 23:50:00  -8.6  7.7   0.0213  0.9820  0.0213  1.6316  1.0  46.810
1 2008-01-24 23:55:00  -6.7  7.7   0.0213  0.9824  0.0213  1.6321  1.0  46.802
2 2008-01-25 00:00:00  -1.7  7.7   0.0213  0.9828  0.0213  1.6328  1.0  46.799
3 2008-01-25 00:05:00 -32.0  7.7   0.0213  0.9835  0.0213  1.6334  1.0  46.757
4 2008-01-25 00:10:00 -11.1  7.7   0.0213  0.9842  0.0213  1.6342  1.0  46.742
```

```
print (df2)
                  Date     A      B
0  2008-01-24 23:50:00  6.55  186.9
1  2008-01-24 23:51:00  6.84  188.6
2  2008-01-24 23:52:00  7.14  188.1
3  2008-01-24 23:53:00  7.12  189.9
4  2008-01-24 23:54:00  7.45  188.6
5  2008-01-24 23:55:00  7.52  190.5
6  2008-01-24 23:56:00  7.29  189.5
7  2008-01-24 23:57:00  7.07  192.4
8  2008-01-24 23:58:00  7.33  193.7
9  2008-01-24 23:59:00  7.25  192.6
10 2008-01-25 00:02:00  6.52  191.0
11 2008-01-25 00:03:00  6.58  189.0
12 2008-01-25 00:04:00  6.43  190.5
13 2008-01-25 00:05:00  6.60  188.3
14 2008-01-25 00:06:00  6.52  188.7
15 2008-01-25 00:07:00  6.75  188.9
16 2008-01-25 00:08:00  6.62  188.9
17 2008-01-25 00:09:00  6.26  188.8
18 2008-01-25 00:10:00  6.60  193.2
```

You can first convert columns `Date` [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df1.index = df1['Date'].dt.to_period('h')
df2['per'] = df2['Date'].dt.to_period('h')

print (df1)

                                Date     A    B        C       D       E  \
Date                                                                       
2008-01-24 23:00 2008-01-24 23:50:00  -8.6  7.7   0.0213  0.9820  0.0213   
2008-01-24 23:00 2008-01-24 23:55:00  -6.7  7.7   0.0213  0.9824  0.0213   
2008-01-25 00:00 2008-01-25 00:00:00  -1.7  7.7   0.0213  0.9828  0.0213   
2008-01-25 00:00 2008-01-25 00:05:00 -32.0  7.7   0.0213  0.9835  0.0213   
2008-01-25 00:00 2008-01-25 00:10:00 -11.1  7.7  ;0.0213  0.9842  0.0213   

                       F    G       H  
Date                                   
2008-01-24 23:00  1.6316  1.0  46.810  
2008-01-24 23:00  1.6321  1.0  46.802  
2008-01-25 00:00  1.6328  1.0  46.799  
2008-01-25 00:00  1.6334  1.0  46.757  
2008-01-25 00:00  1.6342  1.0  46.742
```

```
print (df2)
                  Date     A      B              per
0  2008-01-24 23:50:00  6.55  186.9 2008-01-24 23:00
1  2008-01-24 23:51:00  6.84  188.6 2008-01-24 23:00
2  2008-01-24 23:52:00  7.14  188.1 2008-01-24 23:00
3  2008-01-24 23:53:00  7.12  189.9 2008-01-24 23:00
4  2008-01-24 23:54:00  7.45  188.6 2008-01-24 23:00
5  2008-01-24 23:55:00  7.52  190.5 2008-01-24 23:00
6  2008-01-24 23:56:00  7.29  189.5 2008-01-24 23:00
7  2008-01-24 23:57:00  7.07  192.4 2008-01-24 23:00
8  2008-01-24 23:58:00  7.33  193.7 2008-01-24 23:00
9  2008-01-24 23:59:00  7.25  192.6 2008-01-24 23:00
10 2008-01-25 00:02:00  6.52  191.0 2008-01-25 00:00
11 2008-01-25 00:03:00  6.58  189.0 2008-01-25 00:00
12 2008-01-25 00:04:00  6.43  190.5 2008-01-25 00:00
13 2008-01-25 00:05:00  6.60  188.3 2008-01-25 00:00
14 2008-01-25 00:06:00  6.52  188.7 2008-01-25 00:00
15 2008-01-25 00:07:00  6.75  188.9 2008-01-25 00:00
16 2008-01-25 00:08:00  6.62  188.9 2008-01-25 00:00
17 2008-01-25 00:09:00  6.26  188.8 2008-01-25 00:00
18 2008-01-25 00:10:00  6.60  193.2 2008-01-25 00:00
```

Then found [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) `periods` by condition:

```
pers = df2.loc[df2.B > 190, 'per'].unique()
print (pers)
[Period('2008-01-24 23:00', 'H') Period('2008-01-25 00:00', 'H')]
```

Last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) all rows in `df1`:

```
print (df1.drop(pers))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
Index: []
```

EDIT by  comment:

If `df1` and `df2` have [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) use:

```
df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')
df2['per'] = df2.index.to_period('h')
```

Comment: How did you get:
    df1.index = df1.Date.dt.to_period('h')
To work? I get DataFrame object has no attribute 'Date'

It thinks that the Date column isn't a column but the heading starts on "A"

Comment: ok, I found error in code - you need add column `H` to `df1`. Please check solution with `read_csv` too.

Comment: The names were arbbitary: In practice I should have said: 

    aethalometer=['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation']
    df1=pd.read_csv('Output14.csv', index_col=0, names=aethalometer, parse_dates=True)

But then doing df1.Date does the above error

Comment: Yes, I think I understand - you need use `[]` `df1.index = df1['Date'].dt.to_period('h')
    df2['per'] = df2['Date'].dt.to_period('h')`, see edit.

Comment: `names=['Date','Wind Speed','Wind Direction']`
`df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('all_test.csv'), index_col=0, names=names, parse_dates=True)`



`aethalometer=['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation']`
`df1=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('Output14.csv'), index_col=0, names=aethalometer, parse_dates=True)`

`df1.index = df1['Date'].dt.to_period('h')`
`df2['per'] = df2['Date'].dt.to_period('h') `

Comment: It is interesting, what return `print df1.info()` ?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciiate your help :)

Is it because the Date isn't actually a column its the index already? 



`print(df2.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, all_test.csv to all_test.csv
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Wind Speed        0 non-null float64
Wind Direction    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 24.0+ bytes
None`

Comment: `print(df1.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, Output14.csv to Output14.csv
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Conc           0 non-null float64
Flow           0 non-null float64
SZ             0 non-null float64
SB             0 non-null float64
RZ             0 non-null float64
RB             0 non-null float64
Fraction       0 non-null float64
Attenuation    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8)
memory usage: 72.0+ bytes`

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it seems you need add one column nmae to parameter `name` - `['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation'‌​, 'test']`, because first column is converted to index.

Comment: If I use this instead
`df1=pd.read_csv('Output14.csv', index_col=0, names=aethalometer, parse_dates=True)` 

i get:


`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 71105 entries, 2004-02-27 15:45:00 to 2008-01-28 12:10:00
Data columns (total 8 columns):

Conc           71105 non-null float64

Flow           71105 non-null float64

SZ             71105 non-null float64

SB             71105 non-null float64

RZ             71105 non-null float64

RB             71105 non-null float64

Fraction       71105 non-null float64

Attenuation    71105 non-null float64
`

Comment: Or if you have datetimeindex in `df1`, you can change `df1.index = df1['Date'].dt.to_period('h')` to `df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')`

Comment: `df1.index = df1.index.to_period('h')` worked for df1 
The df['per'] line says index has no attribute to 'to_period'

Comment: Yes, then use `df2['per'] = df2.index.to_period('h')`

Comment: I add it to answer.

Comment: Thanks-giving it a go now, it takes a long time to run. 

Thanks for your help again! Really appreciate it

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And thank you for accepting

Comment: May have spoke to soon, the pers works perfectly- but saying df1.drops(pers) did nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115416/discussion-between-sle-and-jezrael).

Comment: Any ideas as to why the df1.drops(pers) doesn't remove any of df1?

Comment: It is interesting - what is `df1.index` before `drop`?

Comment: PeriodIndex(['2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', '2005-03-01 12:00', ... '2005-03-03 03:00', '2005-03-03 04:00', '2005-03-03 05:00', '2005-03-03 06:00', '2005-03-03 07:00', '2005-03-03 08:00', '2005-03-03 09:00', '2005-03-03 10:00', '2005-03-03 11:00', '2005-03-03 12:00'], dtype='int64', name='Date', length=109, freq='H')

Comment: printing (pers) gives:
`[Period('2004-03-03 10:00', 'H') Period('2004-03-03 11:00', 'H')]`

Where/what is the H from?
Is that for hour?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is hour. And problem is with matching dates e.g. years - in `per` are `2004` and in `df1.index` are `2005`- there is not matching, so `drop` function delete nothing.

Comment: Oh ****. I didn't see that! I selected bits from both csv files to check it was working , made sure I had same dates. So sorry! WIll check with right years tomorrow